My Character only jumps occasionally :( how to fix it?
How to make my character jump every time I press the Up Arrow key?
So far he only jumps every 5-7 presses on the key.
I can't figure it out myself.
I have watched YouTube and Unity forums, but didn't find the answer.
Every answer I see says to check in the Update method and not in the FixedUpdate, but I've tried to check in them both and it seems fine.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller; 
    private Vector3 direction; 
    public float forwardSpeed; 

    private int desiredLane = 1;//0:left 1:middle 2:right 
    public float laneDistance = 4;// distance beetween two lanes 

    public float JumpForce;
    public float Gravity = -20; 
    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>(); 
    }

    private void Jump() 
    {
        direction.y = JumpForce; 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        direction.z = forwardSpeed; {}

        //Gather the imputs on which lane we should be 

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) 
        {
            desiredLane++; 
            if(desiredLane==3)
            desiredLane = 2; 
        }
        
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow)) 
        {
            desiredLane--; 
            if(desiredLane == -1)
            desiredLane = 0; 
        }

        //Calculate where we should be on the future 

        Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position.z * transform.forward + transform.position.y * transform.up; 

        if (desiredLane ==0) 
        {
            targetPosition += Vector3.left * laneDistance; 

        }else if (desiredLane ==2) 
        {
            targetPosition += Vector3.right * laneDistance; 
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition,50 * Time.fixedDeltaTime); 

        if(controller.isGrounded) 
        {   
            
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) 
           {
            Jump();

           } 
        }
         
        else 
        {
            direction.y += Gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }
         
         
          

       
        
    }


    private void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        controller.Move(direction*Time.fixedDeltaTime);   
    }

    
}


Try adding some debug.logs so you can output the value of isGrounded because I am suspecting that's the culprit.

just a side note: Why do you move the controller in FixedUpdate? Afaik the character controller is specifically made to also deal with Move being called from within Update which would reduce complexity a bit .. see API
